# Re-position MyLocation button inside Google Map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In the Google Maps API for Android there is button located at the top-right corner, served to locate you inside the map.

I would like to know if it is possible to relocate this icon that is by default in the API of Google Maps for Android, because at the top I plan to add an EditText as if it were floating.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I can suggest 2 options.
However, I strongly advise you to use the first one - much more classic and simple:

---

1. **Use [Map Padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding)** (recommended)

You can re-position any of the GoogleMap Controls by setting the `Padding` from the corners. In your case, I would set some padding from the top:

`googleMap.setPadding(0, numTop, 0, 0); //numTop = padding of your choice`

It would also change the center position of the Map Camera accordingly, which is great for that kind of use case (adding a title / other floating controls).

---

2. **Disable the button and create one of your own** (less recommended)

Disabling it will be easy:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false)
```

However, creating a new one would be trickier - mostly because it is harder to set a fully-functional one.

1. I would **Create a `FloatingActionButton`** that looks like the one on the Google Maps application ([example](http://hothardware.com/gallery/NewsItem/41034?image=big_google-maps-wpi.jpg&tag=popup)).

   - You can get the Icon from [here](https://material.io/icons/#ic_my_location) (called "My Location")
   - Color the Fab in [Material Grey 300](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette) (maybe 400, can't remember at the moment)
2. Define an **onClick Event** that would move the camera to the user's current location (you're going to have to use [Location Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) for this.

   Sample:

   ```
   //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
   LocationManager locationManager = 
        (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   //Acquire the user's location
   Location selfLocation = locationManager
        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

   //Move the map to the user's location
   LatLng selfLoc = new LatLng(selfLocation.getLatitude(), selfLocation.getLongitude());
   CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(selfLoc, 15);
   googleMap.moveCamera(update);
   ```
3. If you noticed, when you click the "My Location" button, it starts to track you and move the camera accordingly. In order to create that effect, you need to override `googleMap.onCameraMove` and `googleMap.onCameraIdle`, and code your app so whenever the camera is idle, the map will continue to follow the user, and whenever the user moved the camera, it will stop.

   Sample for `onCameraIdle`:

   ```
   //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
   LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                       getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   //Acquire the user's location
   Location selfLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
   LatLng cameraLocation = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

   float[] results = new float[3];
   Location.distanceBetween(selfLocation.getLatitude(), selfLocation.getLongitude(), cameraLocation.latitude, cameraLocation.longitude, results);

   if (results[0] < 30) //30 Meters, you can change that
       googleMap.moveCamera(...) //Move the camera to user's location
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
    View locationButton = ((View) findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
    locationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
    // position on right bottom
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    rlp.setMargins(0, 180, 180, 0);
```

You can set margin where you likely to locate the My location button.

Comment: Not working for some devices